# In which Platform C language Coded?

Tags: windows

I just Likely know that in which platform operating system coded.

as per my knowledge.

Windows kernel written in C language.
Linux kernel is also written in C language.

but remain operating system in?

In which Platform C language is written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Windows kernel and Linux kernels are written in C. Most operating systems tend to be.
There are operating systems written in other languages though, the [Chorus kernel](http://www.cdk3.net/oss/Ed2/Chorus.pdf) for example is written in C++.

Most C compilers are also written in C. That has the advantage that once you managed to get the compiler running on the machine (generally by compiling it on another machine that already has a working compiler/cross compiler), the machine itself can compile updates to its own compiler without maintaining yet another compiler.

Comment: Perhaps a bit nitpicky, but significant parts of operating system kernels are written in Assembler, mostly those that are operating low-level on devices, like drivers.

Comment: if C language is written in assembly language .then in which language assembler is written???

Comment: Nowadays, an assembler might be written in almost any language, most likely C.  Obviously the *first* assembler was written in machine code and had to be hand-assembled, but that's a long time ago now.

Answer (score 1):

Most parts of the C compiler (like gcc) are written in C themselves. Of course you would need something to bootstrap your compiler such that it can compile itself. That would then be a lower type language like [Assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

Comment: I think nowadays to support a new platform it's probably usually a cross-compiler which will generate the bootstrap compiler for the new platform.

Comment: Yeah, but initially they had to start somewhere without a higher-level language, right? ;)

Comment: Of course; but that was long ago. I doubt someone would start a new compiler using only assembler now :)

Comment: if C language is written in assembly language .then in which language assembler is written???

Comment: what you mean with machine code or painful..but assembly language is machine language.(low level language)

Comment: Assembler is not the same as machine code. The lowest level of machine code you can write is microcode on the CPU level. Call the instruction set the CPU offers you, which I ALREADY KNOW THE QUESTION is implemented with electronics (logical gates like AND, OR, XOR) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The C language is one of many languages that are considered to be [Self Hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting) - that is to say that the compiler can compile its own source code, which is written in the same language that the compiler is designed to compile.

You might also want to look into the process of [Bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29), which is the process used to get the first compiler for a particular language to run on a given platform - as others have noted, this can be by way of cross-compiling, or by writing the original compiler in a different language, though other techniques are possible.

Answer (score -2):

First off, you might want to improve your question with actual sentences.

Second,
C is not written in a platform, it is written in another programming language.
Most compilers are written in assembler, a somewhat readable version of the actual machine codes sent to the processor.
I don't know if there are other compilers, written in some intermediary language but eventually, everything boils down to assembler code, which compiles to machine code.

Comment: Nope, most C compilers are written in C (and if the C1001 errors are correct, MSVC++ seems even to be written in C++ in some parts).

Comment: I was trying to keep the answer simple by stating that it eventually comes down to assembler, as it seems confusing that the C compiler is written in C itself. But you are correct in correcting me.

Comment: The point is that nowadays compilers are complicated beasts, and cross-compiling the compiler is way simpler than to write a simple C compiler directly in assembly.

Comment: Sorry, for the use of improper sentences in question..if C language is written in assembly language .then in which language assembler is written???